# How to sort results on android from SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i need to display multiple database tables to seperate textviews.

So i need to pull all 'appointments' from a table and sort them to display in separate textviews on the mainActivity such as txtMonday, txtTuesday, txtWednesday

The database is designed to store the day along with the other details:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + TABLE_AP + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_DAY + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TIME + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_DURATION + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null);";
```

This is how i attempt to call it through MainActivity:
(I also will be calling it with onCreate)

```
  public void onResume (){
      APData = new AppointmentDataSource(this);
      APData.open();
      List<Appointment> appointments = APData.retrieveAllAppointments();
      APData.close();
```

AppointmentDataSource:

```
public List<Appointment> retrieveAllAppointments () {
    List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_AP, , null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();


    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Appointment ap = cursorToBk(cursor);
        appointments.add(ap);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return appointments;        
}
```

Also for the days, i used radio buttons to choose between monday / tue / wed / thur / fri 
so i store the day with :

```
createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        findRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioDay);
        int selectedId = findRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);


        String day=radioButton.getText().toString();
        String time=txtTime.getText().toString();
        String duration=txtDuration.getText().toString();
        String description=txtDescription.getText().toString();

        APData.insert(day, time, duration, description);
        APData.close();
        finish();
      }

    });
```

and the XML/strings for them:

```
<string name="RadioMon">Mon</string>
<string name="RadioTue">Tue</string>
<string name="RadioWed">Wed</string>
<string name="RadioThu">Thur</string>
<string name="RadioFri">Fri</string>
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want to sort? explain better please

Comment: The last argument of the query method of SQLiteDatabase holds the "orderBy" parameter of the SQL function. More infos here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Ah sorry Tenhouse, I want to sort them by day, and put the Time / duration / description under the correct textview day

Comment: But how will i be able to use 'OrderBy day' to separate the rows to the individual day textviews.

Comment: So for the only way i think i can do it is by creating multiple RetrieveAllAppointments and just change them to 'RetrieveMondayAppointments' / 'RetrieveTuesdayAppointments' ect ect and just filter out all the days that are not monday or tuesday or w/e

Answer (score 1):

In your datamodel you should have a class that manipulates the Appointments, so when you retrieve all your appointments from the database just filter them by `appointments[i].Day`, or something like that, based on how your Appointment class is created. You don't need to explicitly create different DB selects for each of them.

```
  public void onResume (){
  APData = new AppointmentDataSource(this);
  APData.open();
  List<Appointment> appointments = APData.retrieveAllAppointments();
  APData.close();
  TextView tvMonday = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMonday);
  TextView tvTuesday = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTuesday);
  ... (all your days textViews).
  for(Iterator<Appointment> i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();){ 
  Appointment item = i.next();
     if(item.Day.equals("Monday") tvMonday.append(item.ToString());
     //same for the rest of your textViews
  }
```

Should be something like this.

Comment: So, i have to sort it like appointments[i].day and then change the text values of the textviews from the retrieveAllAppointments method? Because i can only return 1 value or 1 list and not sure how to sort it once its been returned.

Comment: Well as far as I understood you return all the appointments from the DB. And an object of `type Appointment` should have a property `Appointment.Day`. And yes, I am saying that you could try to sort it by `appointments[i].day` and then decide where to send each objects on your layout.

Comment: Hey man, you able to show me some example code and where i need to put it? Cant get this working sorry.

Comment: Check the update, I've posted a piece of code, hope it helps you.